# Previewing my HTML in Safari Using TextWrangler.

Tags: html

I've begin to construct a simple website with TextWrangler, and I have a question. In the online tutorial I'm following, the guy previews his website in Chrome. However, he is using Notepad++. Is there any way I can preview my code in Safari using TextWrangler? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If it's a single page you can just open it in Safari with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>.

If it's more elaborate, store it to `~/Sites`, enable Web Sharing in the Sharing Preferences and point Safari to `http://localhost/~YOUR-USER-NAME/WHATEVER-YOU-CALLED-IT.html`